# What is the purpose of installing Linux alongside Android?

Tags: android, linux

Ok, so I have been doing some research on how to run a web server on Android, particularly with Node.js. It seems like if you want do this on Android, you must unlock it by rooting it, then install a form of Linux alongside it. What is the purpose of installing a form of Linux alongside Android, when Android is already running on its own form of Linux. Would I install the webserver on the Linux that is running alongside Android, or would I use that Linux to SSH into the Linux that is running under Android, then install the webserver there? Is the only purpose of installing Linux alongside Android to gain access through SSH to the already running Linux under the Android Java application? Thanks.

Comment: "It seems like if you want to develop on Android, you must unlock it by rooting it, then install a form of Linux alongside it" -- there are a million-plus apps for Android on the Play Store. Virtually none were developed by installing "a form of Linux alongside" Android.

Comment: I am trying to run a full web server on Android.

Comment: Do you mind if we ask why?  I can't imagine anyone recommended this to you as an optimal way to run a web server.

Comment: I need to run a web server on Android. I also need to run MySql and Node/PHP as well. On top of that, I need to write an application that connects to the bluetooth port on Android. Yes my work is cut out for me! Data: Bluetooth->Java->MySql->Node/PHP->Ajax->Browser. Thanks.

Comment: Well try open source software like http://droidphp.github.io and phpforandroid which require no rooting.

Comment: That may work. I wanted to do the long method because I'm really trying to learn Linux and understand how everything works, rather than install a package. I'm done with windows, and the only language I know other than .Net is Javascript/Java. With Node.js, I could run a full web server and application using Javascript and Java on the server side without learning another language like PHP. Most importantly though, I want to understand the way Linux and Android work together. Thanks.

Comment: All the time I spent in my life learning Windows when Unix derivatives turned out to be the future. Such a sad story.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Android's Linux is different to the Linux we used in other distro (say Ubuntu, RedHat).

It is different from "standard" Linux in these aspects:

- standard library
- services/daemons
- the way to start programs
- sandboxing model
- not fully POSIX compliant

So you have to either port your current code base to Android (which may or may not be an easy task depending on the project) or install a "standard" Linux and `chroot`.

Comment: Ok. So let's say for example I want to run MySql and Node Web server, and connect to it from the browser on Android. What you are saying is that since the linux distribution on Android is different from mainstream linux, I must install a mainstream linux alongside Androids linux because MySql and Node are only designed for the mainstream versions of Linux? Thanks

Comment: Yes, unless MySql and Node are ported to Android. FYI, paddybyers started [a project](https://github.com/paddybyers/anode) to port Node to Android.

Answer (score 0):

Android's Linux is designed to be invisible and to support the operation of apps that run on top of it and are installed via the Play Store.

Installing Linux means that you can go to town and do heaps of cool things (upside), and also terribly screw up the device operation and the user experience (downside).

With the app "Linux Deploy" you can run Linux in a container on your Android device. Then you can SSH into it using Juice SSH or similar, and run any kind of server that you want, including node.js.

You can use Kingroot to get root on your Android device.

Another option is to use GNURoot. This allows you to install a containerized/chrooted Linux install without needing root on the device, using fakeroot. There are some things you can't do with fakeroot, like `ping` - but it does most things.